# Can I have a Reactive return type in a function to be exposed in a Faas?

Tags: reactive-programming, serverless, micronaut

Can I have in a function that I would like to expose in a Faas a Reactive Return Type ?
This function is supposed to execute a call to a remote service parse and transform the response to be consumed by another service.
From the [Micronaut documentation on Serveless Fuctions](https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#serverlessFunctions) I don't see a reference that the return type can be a reactive type.

Thank you, kindly
  Luis Oscar Trigueiros

Answer (score 0):

From the docs

> In addition, functions have an input and/or an output. The input is represented by the accepted argument and represents the body consumed by the function and the output is represented by the return value of the function. The input and the output should be either a Java primitive or simple type (int, String etc.) or

[[AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-req-resp.html) return types:

> AWS Lambda supports the following input/output types for a handler:
>
> Simple Java types (AWS Lambda supports the String, Integer, Boolean, Map, and List types)
> POJO (Plain Old Java Object) type
> Stream type (If you do not want to use POJOs or if Lambda's serialization approach does not meet your needs, you can use the byte stream implementation. For more information, see Example: Using Stream for Handler Input/Output (Java).)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I so internally I will have the reactive service that the function  will consume in blocking way.